# Not entering Controller while validating with Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core restful web API. My problem is that I have a server validation inside my controller to check for view model (`Contact.cs`) validation.

However when I test my `POST` action `CreateContact` in the controller, the action is never entered, but it is validated correctly according to the data annotations I have inside my `Contact.cs` class.

I don't understand why validation is happening before entering controller. I thought, that in web API, server validation will be checked in `Controller` according to the `ModelState`. Then my `ModelState.IsValid` check seems useless.

My view model:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Piece of my Controller action which is never entered.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ContactsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateContact(ViewModels.Contacts.Contact contact)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ApiController` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apicontrollerattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that you have applied to your controller comes with certain conventions. One of that is that the passed model is *automatically* validated before entering your controller action.

So this effectively removes the need to check the `ModelState.IsValid` inside each method.

You can read more about the `ApiController` attribute [in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute) and [in this blog post](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/02/exploring-the-apicontrollerattribute-and-its-features-for-asp-net-core-mvc-2-1/) both which also cover the other conventions the attribute includes.

If you don’t want this behavior and still want to be able to do this manually in your controller action, check out [this question on disabling the functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51870603/216074).