# Handling Auto Model Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm having a problem in which whenever I input a string request for a 
integer and boolean data type. I'm having a weird error messages, caused by the NET CORE2.1 new feature Auto model validation.

Here is the request

```
{   
    "EmailAddress" : "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "EmailAddressConfirm" : "johndoe@gmail.com",
    "FirstName" : "KL",
    "MiddleName": "M",
    "LastName" : "Lawingco",
    "InquiryTypeID": "asda" ,
    "InquiryContent" : "test",
    "Validation" : true,
    "TermsAndCondition" : false
}
```

And it will throw an error like this

> Could not convert string to integer: asda. Path 'InquiryTypeID', line 7, position 26.

Note that I'm using also FluentValidation, but since 2.1 the auto model validation was introduce. My question is can I modify the error message whenever a wrong input were given to a int or boolean datatype

I tried turning off the Auto model Validation using this

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

But it also kill my FluentValidation

Here is my model

```
public class NewInquiry
{
    public string EmailAddress{ get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddressConfirm { get; set; }

    public int? InquiryTypeID { get; set; }

    public string InquiryContent { get; set; }

    public bool Validation { get; set; }

    public bool TermsAndCondition { get; set; }

}
```

Hope you can help me, Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439664/customize-automatic-response-on-validation-error - this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a modification of error response structure . :( I already able to mdofiy my error structure using Filters

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can customize/localize all model input *ModelBinding* error messages.

in your startup file you can access the ModelBindingMessageProvider and set all model binding messages:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddMvcOptions(o =>
    {
        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x, y) =>
            string.Format("The value '{0}' is not valid for '{1}'", x, y));

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingBindRequiredValueAccessor((x) => 
            string.Format("A value for the '{0}' property was not provided", x));

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingKeyOrValueAccessor(() => 
            "A value is required");

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetMissingRequestBodyRequiredValueAccessor(() => 
            "A non-empty request body is required");

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => 
            string.Format("The value '{0}' is not valid", x));

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor(() => 
            "The supplied value is invalid");

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetNonPropertyValueMustBeANumberAccessor(() => 
            "The field must be a number");

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => 
            string.Format("The supplied value is invalid for {0}", x));

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) => 
            string.Format("The value '{0}' is invalid", x));

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor((x) => 
            string.Format("The field '{0}' must be a number", x));

        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor((x) => 
            string.Format("The field '{0}' must not be null", x));
    });
```

same approach can be used for localization as well