# How to get json parsing error details in POST requests handlers that use FromBody

Tags: asp.net-core

I am creating a web api that receives data in a POST request in form of a JSON object in the body.

The real DataObj has many more fields so I simplify it to the following to show a specific sample where parsing must fail:

```
public class DataObj
{
   public int Value { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubTables([FromBody] DataObj data)
{
  if (data == null)
  {
    string parsingErrorDetails = "";

    // ? how can I check which kind of parsing erros happend?

    return BadRequest("Failed to parse JSON with error: " + parsingErrorDetails);
  }
  ..
}
```

Typically if you post valid JSON data to the service (like `{ "value": 1 }` it just works fine.
But in the above example a valid JSON body would also be one like `{ "value": 6123456789 }` parsing fails because the value exceeds Int32.MaxValue.

In my case the body has an object with several fields which makes it complicated to analyze the problem if I just return 404 Bad Request.
My goal is that I want to be able to report this specific problem back to the caller so that the caller has an easier option to analyze the root cause of the call.
Best without loosing the option to use `[FromBody]`.

Is there a way to query details why the data object was null as in the sample above so that I can report it back to the caller?

Comment: After I got the solution from the linked question I was wondering how to check the model state in a central location to not being forced to do the model validity check in every single request handler. A simple approach can be found [here](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/validate-model-state-automatically-asp-net-core-2-0/)

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET Core 2.1, you can take advantage of the [`[ApiController]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#annotate-class-with-apicontrollerattribute) attribute for automatic ModelState validation. You can even [customise the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439664/customize-automatic-response-on-validation-error/51442067#51442067).

Answer (score 0):

I would check values on the setter properties of DataObj, throwing an exception in case the value doesn't fit.

```
public class DataObj
{
    private int myInt;

    public int MyInt{
        get{ return myInt;}

        set
        {
            if (value > int.MaxValue)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value for MyInt");
            myInt = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (value > int.MaxValue)` - it will always be false

Comment: The setter will never even run for what is essentially the same reason as above.