# Proper way to return calculation result from Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm creating an API that will take parameters (type double) and return the result.
ex.
    http://localhost:54897/api/Power/Nominal/6/-2

In the browser, I'll see:
4.0

Here's the code I have so far:

**Model**

```
public class PowerModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(0,50)]
    public  double PowerFront { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(-50,-1)]
    public  double PowerBack { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public  double Result { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Power")]
public class PowerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Nominal/{powerFront}/{powerBack}")]
    public double NominalPower(PowerModel powerModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {   
            powerModel.Result = Power.NominalPower(powerModel.PowerFront, powerModel.PowerBack);
            return powerModel.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;           
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, I can take in parameters, validate them and return a numeric result.

Something doesn't seem right though. I don't want to return 0 on an invalid model state, I want to return a message in the event of invalid input.

What would be the best way to take in parameters (preferably named), validate  those parameters with attributes, perform a calculation, return a value on successful input or show error message on incorrect input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that HTTP Status Codes are used for. In your successful case, `200` is returned to indicate that the request was successful. For an invalid `ModelState`, it's common to return `400` (which indicates a bad request was made).

To achieve this in ASP.NET Core, you can take advantage of [`ActionResult<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#actionresultt-type). Here's a complete example of how this would affect `NominalPower`:

```
[HttpGet("Nominal/{powerFront}/{powerBack}")]
public ActionResult<double> NominalPower(PowerModel powerModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    powerModel.Result = Power.NominalPower(powerModel.PowerFront, powerModel.PowerBack);
    return powerModel.Result;
}
```

In the example above, we pass `ModelState` into the `BadRequest` method, which will be serialised as JSON to show a list of errors that occurred when validing the model. If you'd prefer not to include this, you can just omit the `ModelState` argument when calling `BadRequest`.

---

Alternatively, you could simply decorate your `PowerController` class with the [`ApiController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#annotation-with-apicontroller-attribute) attribute, which will cause any requests that result in an invalid `ModelState` to *automatically* return a `400` with JSON-serialised errors. Here's an example of that approach:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Power")]
[ApiController]
public class PowerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Nominal/{powerFront}/{powerBack}")]
    public double NominalPower(PowerModel powerModel)
    {
        powerModel.Result = Power.NominalPower(powerModel.PowerFront, powerModel.PowerBack);
        return powerModel.Result;
    }
}
```

In this version, there's no need to check `ModelState` as that's already been checked thanks to the presence of the `ApiController` attribute. You can even customise the automatic response that gets returned, if needed, as I've detailed in another answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439664/customize-automatic-response-on-validation-error/51442067#51442067).