# ASP .NET Core Endpoint returns different Content Types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

While testing my endpoints I recognized that an endpoint returned different Content Types when sending different input values.
For instance: The endpoint returns a Supplier when an ID is given. If the HTTP Status Code is 200 the content type is "`application/json; charset=utf-8; v=1.0`".
But when I submit bullshit like a random string instead of an integer, obviously the api returns a HTTP 400. The content type now is "`application/json; charset=utf-8`". The "`v=1.0`" is missing.
It seems trivial but our integration tests check if the Content Type is like the expected `application/json; charset=utf-8; v=1.0`.

Also, we defined in the `Startup.cs`: `options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);`

Endpoint code:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
{
    var body = await _lieferantenService.GetById(id);
    return Ok(body);
}
```

Does anybody encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: You're using api versioning. Now we've a request that we cannot read and so there's a 400 response before it reaches your api. That said, there is simply no version available at that point and so it's impossible to return one.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen So basically what you are saying is, that I can't check the content type where I test failure cases because the API version is not available at that point.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen in that Case i would expect an 404 Not found. Not an 400 Bad request

Comment: Ok, I give up - seems like it's too long ago I've worked with api versioning.

Comment: looks like your response is required to has a suffix of `v=1.0` in the content type? The problem is where it (or which code) appends that `v=1.0`? That's of course not by the `asp.net core` framework. If you find that code responsible for appending that `v=1.0`, that code possibly has some bug ***or*** some other code overwrites the response content type somewhere (later in the pipeline)

Comment: We discussed the issue internally and came to the conclusion that something in the middleware blocks the request before it even touches the controller. So, the HTTP 400 seems alright in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that the response comes from a middleware and not from your code.

I think the middleware that validates input or the one that is responsible for model bindings. (Mapping bullshit to integer).

To customize the Response use `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` of `ApiBehaviorOptions`.

See answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51442067/83039.

Comment: That seems reasonable...we have quite some stuff configured (or on our own developed) in the middleware.